# Highcharts show stacked column total sum always on top (even negatives)

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a chart with stacked columns. Positive and negative values.
Example:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
        text: 'show total sum always on top (also negatives)',
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['positives', 'mixed', 'negatives']
        },
        yAxis: {
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'center'
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            plotLines: [{
                        color: '#333',
                        width: 1,
                        dashStyle: 'dash',
                        value: 0
                    }],
          stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'center',
            style: {
              fontWeight: 'normal',
              color: 'red',
              fontSize: '10px'
            },
            
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
              pointWidth: 40
          },
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    color: '#FFFFFF'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [10, -10, -5]
        }, 
        {
            data: [15, -5, -5]
        },
        {
            data: [10, 20, -5]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

`http://jsfiddle.net/tmrLwj17/1/`

What I need to achieve, is that I need to display sum of negatives and positives always on top. It works fine when there are only positive values.
I was looking into similar fiddle:     `http://jsfiddle.net/sph1LjtL/5/`
Sum of negatives always are below. I need them on top.
Thanks!

[image: expected top labels]

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/0upL93mb/

I compute custom values for labels in `chart.events.render` because there I'm able to easily access and manipulate y axis stacks (`redrawEnabled` flag prevents infinite recursive loop - `Chart.redraw()` calls `render` event):

Refer to this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/5t9z9sto/

I compute custom values for labels in `chart.events.render` because there I'm able to easily access and manipulate y axis stacks (`redrawEnabled` flag prevents infinite recursive loop - `Chart.redraw()` calls `render` event):

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  events: {
    render: function() {

      if (redrawEnabled) {
        redrawEnabled = false;

        var stacks = this.yAxis[0].stacks,
          yAxis = this.yAxis[0];

        // show some additional space for the negative column labels
        if (yAxis.max <= 0) {
          yAxis.setExtremes(null, 5);
        }

        for (var prop in stacks['-column']) {
          var negColumn = stacks['-column'][prop],
            posColumn; // corresponding positive column

          if (stacks.column) {
            posColumn = stacks.column[prop]
          }

          if (posColumn) {
            // add custom properties that will be used in stackLabels.formatter
            posColumn.totalToDisplay = posColumn.total + negColumn.total;
            negColumn.hideStackLabel = true;
          } else { // change the position of the negative stack label
            negColumn.label.alignOptions.verticalAlign = 'top';
            negColumn.label.alignOptions.y = -8;
            negColumn.hideStackLabel = false;
          }
        }

        // stackLabels.formatter launches before events.load so the chart needs to be redrawn to launch it again
        this.redraw(true);
        redrawEnabled = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I use them in `stackLabels.foramtter:`

```
    formatter: function() {
      return this.hideStackLabel ? '' : this.totalToDisplay || this.total;
    }
```

Then I use them in `stackLabels.foramtter:`

```
    formatter: function() {
      return this.hideStackLabel ? '' : this.totalToDisplay || this.total;
    }
```

Comment: this looks really good. thank you.
but is there any way to update those labels on after legend click. looks like after legend filtering they are in some cases again displayed below also..

Comment: @auri.borealis please specify in which cases.

Comment: in your example: 1) unselect series2 2) unselect series1 3) select series1 -> for middle columns both labels are visible

Comment: also if: unselect series3, then middle column has no label

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer and updated the example.

Comment: now it looks even better. thank you.
only thing which i dont understand is.. why, when i have only nagative data the labels are below.

series: [
      {
        data: [-1, -10, -5]
      }, 
      {
        data: [-15, -5, -5]
      }, 
      {
        data: [-10, -20, -5]
      },
    ]
is there some way to force this? when i add at least 1 positive value then labels are again on top. if the data is only negatives and zero then labels are not displayed at all..

Comment: I did another update of my post and fiddle. I added `if (stacks.column)` - condition to prevent the error in the case you explained in your comment. Here's a separate fiddle that shows it: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/5t9z9sto/

Comment: You're right - thanks for pointing that out. I was calling `setExtremes` unnecessarily in some cases. I've just updated the post. Let me know if everything is fine now.